# mySQL partitions can not be imported

Tags: mysql, partition

We have migrated a laravel project from linux to windows environment. The project got migrated successfully and the site is working just fine.

When a developer looked into mysql database, he noticed that Partition created in old mysql(linux) are not there in new mysql db(Windows).

> Old Server mySQL version: Server version: 5.6.39 - MySQL Community
>   Server (GPL)
>
> New Server mySQL version: Server version: 5.6.40 - MySQL Community
>   Server (GPL)

We had simply exported the database from old server and imported in new one. Any idea?

Comment: Did you have data in the missing partitions ?

Comment: Yes, checked with the developer and he says we had data in old db partition.

Comment: Are you saying that the new table was not `PARTITIONed`?  What percentage of the rows are missing?